# Is it possible to exclude grails plugin from production environment?

Tags: grails, development-environment, production-environment, grails-plugin

I would like to use certain plugin in development environment, but would like to exclude this plugin from production and from generated war. What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you give me solution for grails 2.4.3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using plugin scopes.  From http://grails.org/1.1+Release+Notes:

Plugins can now be scoped using either the environment or predefined build scopes:

```
def environments = ['dev', 'test']
def scopes = [excludes:'war']
```

The plugins will only load in those environments and will not be packaged into the WAR file. This allows "development-only" plugins to not be packaged for production use.

Comment: How to configure this?I am trying compile ":angular-annotate-asset-pipeline:2.0.2"{
   def environments = ['dev', 'test']
  } but getting error

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that there is a way to achieve this without editing the plugin itself (as Jean pointed out)

If you have control over the plugin then that will work, but if you just wanted to configure this as you were 'using' it, then you will need to copy and run a patched version of the plugin with your modifications. You'd customizing it by utilizing a custom location for that plugin in your grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to exclude the plugin in certain environment, you need to do this:

```
runtime (':plugin:version') {
    if (Environment.current == Environment.PRODUCTION) {
        export = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the excludes property in your config.groovy:

```
production {
         grails.plugin.excludes='console,classDiagram'
}
```

But there seems to be some confusion as to if it will exclude it from both 'run-app' and 'war'.  I will try to check today and verify