# error in deploying war when code coverage (cobertura) plugin in grails is used

Tags: unit-testing, grails, code-coverage

I have 2 different Grails applications using 2 different versions of the code coverage plugin. The first uses version 1.1.8 (old, I know) and when I build and deploy a war file, all is well.

However, the 2nd one is another matter. I installed the plugin as directed in the guide and the installed version is 1.2.2. When I generate the war, no error is thrown. However, when I deploy on Tomcat, I encounter an error. I checked the logs and this is what came out:

```
2011-04-13 23:23:11,927 [Thread-2] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CodeCoverageGrailsPlugin
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CodeCoverageGrailsPlugin
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
2011-04-13 23:23:37,995 [http-8080-3] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CodeCoverageGrailsPlugin
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CodeCoverageGrailsPlugin
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
2011-04-13 23:24:48,313 [http-8080-3] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CodeCoverageGrailsPlugin
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CodeCoverageGrailsPlugin
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Thing is, I've been googling but it seems like this is a one-off problem... Any thoughts??? For me to generate a war now, I have to UNinstall the plugin everytime... something you can't do when you move the app to automated builds! :(

Btw, I'm using:
Tomcat 6
Java 1.6
Grails 1.3.6

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!
Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783487/is-it-possible-to-exclude-grails-plugin-from-production-environment) You shouldn't normally need to use the code coverage plugin in a war file so just exclude it.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! But now, my question is, how to use it? And whether it should be placed in Config.groovy or BuildConfig.groovy? These variables were defined for Grails 1.1 and I'm wondering if it's still supported with Grails 1.3.6...