# How to exclude a plugin from development environment in Grails 3?

Tags: grails-plugin, grails3

I would like to disable a specific plugin while running in development mode. Is there a generic way to achieve this in Grails 3.x?

I found the following solutions for Grails 2.x, but they won't work for Grails 3 since it uses Gradle instead of BuildConfig.groovy:

- [Exclude plugin for specific environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501444/exclude-plugin-for-specific-environment)
- [Is it possible to exclude grails plugin from production environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783487/is-it-possible-to-exclude-grails-plugin-from-production-environment)

Specifically, I am looking for a way to disable the [LDAP sub-plugin](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ldap/v3/index.html) for the Spring Security plugin, when running in local development mode.

**UPDATE:** I found that `org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin` has an `isEnabled` method, that returns a boolean based on whether the plugin's `profiles` list matches the set of active profiles (e.g. `"development"`).

But the private method that initalizes the `profiles` list (`evaluateProfiles`) appears not to be called anywhere (it should probably be called in `initialisePlugin`, along with other `evaluate*` methods).

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ldap/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/ldap/SpringSecurityLdapGrailsPlugin.groovy), I found that you can specify `grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.active = false` in your configuration to disabled the LDAP plugin. However, this is specific to this plugin, not a general solution.